# Why do I get a warning and negative numbers when I try to project the world population in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a quadratic model to study the evolution of the world population. I would like to display the evolution of the world population until 2100 using the quadratic model.

I took my data from [Worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/world-population-by-year/). I downloaded the page and read it with Pandas.

Here is my code:

```
# Import of modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from types import SimpleNamespace

# Reading the file
Data = 'World Population by Year - Worldometer.html'
Data2 = pd.read_html(Data, header = 0, index_col = 0, decimal = 'M')

Data3 = Data2[0] # We extract a DataFrame from the file
```

Given the year jumps and the fact that the data may not have been reliable prior to 1951, I removed all data prior to 1951 to work only on data from 1951 to 2020.

```
# Delete the years before 1951
data = Data3.drop(Data.index[70:], axis = 0)

# Rename the names of the columns
data.index.names = ['Year'] # Rename the index
data.columns = ['Population', 'Annual change', 'Net change', 'Density (P/Km²)', 'Urban population', 'Urban population (%)'] # Renaming of other columns

population = data['Population']

total_growth = population[2020] - population[1951]

start = population.index[-1] # 1st year of data collected
current = population.index[0] # Last year of data collected
duration = current - start # Duration of the data collection period

start_population = population[start]
population_2020 = population[current]
difference_population = population_2020 - start_population

annual_growth = total_growth / duration

parameters = SimpleNamespace(start = start, end = current, start_population = start_population, annual_growth = annual_growth)

def model(parameters, growth_function):
    result = dict()
    result[parameters.start] = parameters.start_population
    
    for t in range(parameters.start, parameters.end):
        evolution = growth_function(t, result[t], parameters)
        result[t + 1] = result[t] + evolution
        
    # We convert the dictionary into a DataFrame in order to plot it
    result_items = result.items() # To obtain an object of type set with the keys  and the values of the dictionary
    result_list = list(result_items) # We then convert the set object into a list
    results = pd.DataFrame(result_list) # Finally we create a DataFrame from a list
    
    results.columns = ['Year', 'World population'] # Name of the columns of the DataFrame
    
    return results

parameters.alpha = parameters.birth_rate - parameters.death_rate

def quadratic(t, population, parameters):
    """Returns the quadratic function"""
    return parameters.alpha * population + parameters.beta * population ** 2

Parameters = SimpleNamespace(start = start, start_population = start_population, alpha = 25 / 1000, beta = -1.8 / 1000, end = 2100)

projection = model(Parameters, quadratic)
projection
```

Here is the result I get by running this code:

|  | Year | World Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1951 | 2.584034e+09 |
| 1 | 1952 | `-1.201902e+16` |
| 2 | 1953 | `-2.600222e+29` |
| 3 | 1954 | `-1.217008e+56` |
| 4 | 1955 | `-2.665994e+109` |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 145 | 2096 | `-inf` |
| 146 | 2097 | `-inf` |
| 147 | 2098 | `-inf` |
| 148 | 2099 | `-inf` |
| 149 | 2100 | `-inf` |

As you can see, I get totally inconsistent results from the first year calculated (i.e. 1952) and I don't know where this dysfunction can come from. Moreover, I get a `RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars` warning when I try to display the results of the simulation even if this does not prevent the result from being displayed.

No matter how hard I look, I can't figure out what's wrong with my code and my initial values. Where do you think these two problems come from?

Comment: I didn't go through all code but when returning your quadratic function, `beta` is always negativ, is this wanted ? or do you maybe want to have it like this: `(parameters.beta * population) ** 2` ...that's for the moment the first thing that I see which could lead to `-inf`

Comment: The negative value of `beta` is wanted in order to have the best fit. However, after seeing the output my first reflex was to put a positive value for `beta`. This solves indeed the problem of negative numbers but it doesn't solve the problem of extremely high powers (higher than `e+16` and going to infinity). Finally, the formula entered is correct `parameters.beta * population ** 2`. It is the quadratic function

Comment: ok, I changed the code back to your original formula and run the code, if you change the code like I offered in my answer, you will get reasonable numbers as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some code to show you why you get the RunTimeError.

```
def quadratic(t, population, parameters):
    """Returns the quadratic function"""
    print(t)
    return parameters.alpha * population + (parameters.beta * population) ** 2

Parameters = SimpleNamespace(start = start, start_population = start_population, alpha = 25 / 1000, beta = -1.8 / 1000, end = 2100)

np.seterr(all='raise')
projection = model(Parameters, quadratic)
projection
```

The 'RunTimeError' is because the numbers are getting too big. The line `np.seterr(all='raise')` in front of your function call changes the warning to an error. In the `quadratic` function I added `print(t)` to see where the error occurs. You will see, if you run your code again, at year 1957 you will get an error because the number in `(parameters.beta * population) ** 2` is too big to be handled by `numpy.float64`
Even if you start to calculate everything in millions, the error will appear at year `2019`.
You need to convert the population to billions.
To do that just add the devision when defining `population` at the beginning.

```
population = data['Population'] --> population = data['Population']/1_000_000_000
```

Done all that projection will show you a table with actual numbers (in billions)

Comment: Indeed dividing the population by `1e9` solves the problem. I understand that `numpy.float64` can't take into account too big numbers but I still don't understand why keeping the population in billions gave negative results

Answer (score 0):

Your beta parameter is negative (`beta = -1.8 / 1000`). According to your quadratic equation

```
parameters.alpha * population + parameters.beta * population ** 2
```

you multiply the variable `population` in the second term by a negative number . And since you also raise it to a power of 2, at some point the second term (death rate) outweighs the first term (birth rate) enough to make the result negative.

Also, in order to avoid the overflow problem, you should measure population in millions instead.

Comment: The negative value of `beta` is wanted in order to have the best possible fit. However, even giving a positive value to `beta` there is still the problem of numbers with extremely high powers (higher than `e+16`, which would mean that we were several quadrillion inhabitants in 1952)